# How to pass the id attribute instead of the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite new to the HTML5 datalists and I noticed that the value section is displayed in-conjunction to the text within the  tag. but I didnt want the value inside the 'id' attribute to be displayed so I placed it into the 'id' tag instead as another storage method. As so:

```
   <td> 
    <input list="to" id="to-selected" style="width: 145px;">
    <datalist id="to"> 
    <option value="4000 Islands, Laos" id="4483"></option>
    </datalist>
   </td>
```

If this is possible, how would I retrieve the value of the id attribute? (I know how to post it if I get the value)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zsb4155d/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show datalist labels but submit the actual value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882361/show-datalist-labels-but-submit-the-actual-value)

Comment: @StephanMuller This is not a dupe of that one. This is asking about how to retrieve the `id` contents, not how to submit the `value` contents.

Comment: @TylerH Once again you're right. The answer is 99% the same, but the question is different. Vote retracted.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option is to use the input event and set the value manually

```js
$('#to-selected').on('input', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).next().find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').data('id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="to" id="to-selected" style="width: 145px;" />
<datalist id="to">
  <option value="4000 Islands, Laos" data-id="4483"></option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to be displayed you can make it hidden and retrieve the value as usual

```
<input type=hidden id="something" value="4483"/>
```

or

```
<input type=text id="something" value="4483" hidden/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get any attribute using query, you use `.attr('attributeName')`:

```
$('datalist').attr('id');
```

If using `data-*` (like in `<input data-id="5"/>`) you can use

```
$('input').data('id');
```

Just keep in mind that if changing `data-*` value with js, no changes will be reflected to DOM element, only to data set in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You just use `attr` event

```
$('#to').on('input', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).next().find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').attr('id'))
})
```