# Angular and datalist

Tags: html, angular, datalist

I need some help understanding how to use the HTML `datalist` with Angular. I have an object here. I would like the dropdown to display the `make and model` of the cars. But when you select a `car`, the `selectedCar` variable should be the entire car object. But the `input` should still only show the `make and model`.

```
  cars = [{
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'GTX',
    color: 'green'
  }, {
    make: 'Ferarri',
    model: 'Enzo',
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    make: 'VW',
    model: 'Amarok',
    color: 'white'
  }]

...

<input list="id-car" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar">
<datalist id="id-car">
  <option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car">{{car.make}} - {{car.model}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Here is a place to play with this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwmwke

Comment: try this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mho3se

Comment: @Chellappan your stackblitz doesn't have modified code

Comment: can you check now

Answer (score 4):

Using datalist with not get you what you wish in this case.. here is the code that partially works. After selecting any element the dropdown will not show as it was showing before.

try using select with option. This link can help you more [DataList in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456071/datalist-in-angular)

html file

```
<input list="id-car" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar" 
value="{{selectedCarObj.model}} - {{selectedCarObj.make}}"
(ngModelChange)="onChange()">
<datalist id="id-car">
  <option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.make">{{car.make}} - {{car.model}}</option>
</datalist>

{{selectedCarObj.model}} - {{selectedCarObj.make}}
```

typescript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  cars = [{
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'GTX',
    color: 'green'
  }, {
    make: 'Ferarri',
    model: 'Enzo',
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    make: 'VW',
    model: 'Amarok',
    color: 'white'
  }];

  selectedCar = "";

  selectedCarObj = {};

  onChange = () => {
    this.selectedCarObj = this.cars.find((c)=> c  .make==this.selectedCar);
    console.log(this.selectedCarObj)
  }
}
```