# How to load XML from an external site server (using AJAX)?

Tags: ajax, xml, xpath, xmlhttprequest

Here I have an example I'm building (with help).

Currently, the `XML` is stored in a data island. But what if I wanted to make a request to an external server? Would I use an `XMLHttpRequest`?

How would I code that in this example, and avoid the Cross Origin XMLHttpRequest problem?

In this example, I've tried playing with `function loadXMLDoc(statelabel)` but without success.

Am I on the right track with this function?

```
function loadXMLDoc( statelabel ) {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myFunction(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "state_data.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

Fully functional code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    SO
    datalist / xml handling
    Q 51200490 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200490/how-to-find-the-node-position-of-a-value-in-an-xml-tree/51201494)
    A 
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO sample</title>
        <script>
 // Setup of keypress event handler, default selection of xml data.
 function setupEH () {
    var n = document.getElementById("myInputId");
    n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById("myButton").click();
        }
    });

    loadXMLDoc('Alabama'); // comment out this line if you want a vanilla UI after loading the html page.
}

// Load the xml document
function loadXMLDoc( statelabel ) {
    // The xml document is retrieved with the following steps:
    //      1. Obtain the (in-document) source as a DOM node.
    //      2. Extract textual content.
    //      3. Instantiate the xml parser (a browser built-in)
    //      4. Parse textual content into an xml document
    //
    //  When retrieving the xml document by means of ajax, these steps will be handled by the library for you - a parsed xml document will be available as a property or through calling a method.
    //
    let x_xmlisland = document.getElementById("template_xml");
    let s_xmlsource = x_xmlisland.textContent; 
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(s_xmlsource, "application/xml");

    myFunction(xmlDoc, statelabel); // Actual work ...
}

// Processing the xml document 
function myFunction(xmlDoc, statelabel) {
    //    debugger; // uncomment to trace

    //
    //  Every bit of information is processed as follows:
    //      - Get the relevant xml subtree ( `UNIT` element of the selected state incl.descendants )
    //      - Extract the textual value.
    //      - Feed the textual value to the Html elements prsenting the result.
    //
    var xpr_current_unit  = xmlDoc.evaluate("/STATE_DATA/UNIT[./STATE[./text() = '"+statelabel+"']]",xmlDoc,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE,null);
    var node_current_unit = xpr_current_unit.iterateNext();

    //
    //  The subsequent calls to xmlDoc.evaluate set the current UNIT element as their context node ('starting point'/'temporary root' for the xpath expression).
    //  The context node is referenced by '.' (dot) 
    //
    var xpr_s   = xmlDoc.evaluate("./STATE/text()",node_current_unit,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_ANY_TYPE,null);
    var node_s  = xpr_s.iterateNext();
    var s       = node_s.textContent
    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = s;

    var xpr_g   = xmlDoc.evaluate("./GDP/text()",node_current_unit,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_ANY_TYPE,null);
    var node_g  = xpr_g.iterateNext();
    var g = "Unknown";
    if ( node_g !== null ) {
        g = node_g.textContent;
    }
    document.getElementById("gdp").innerHTML = g;

    var xpr_p   = xmlDoc.evaluate("./POPULATION/text()",node_current_unit,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_ANY_TYPE,null);
    var node_p  = xpr_p.iterateNext();
    var p = "Unknown";
    if ( node_p !== null ) {
        p = node_p.textContent;
    }
    document.getElementById("population").innerHTML = p;

    // cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437009
    var xpr_u  = xmlDoc.evaluate("count(./preceding::UNIT)+1.",node_current_unit,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_ANY_TYPE,null);
    var n_ucount = xpr_u.numberValue;

    document.getElementById("inputValue").innerHTML = s;
    document.getElementById("nodePosition").innerHTML = n_ucount;
}

// Setup the submit click handler
function ehClick ( ) {
    let node_choice     = document.getElementById('myInputId');
    loadXMLDoc(node_choice.value);
}
        </script>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="setupEH()">
        <script id="template_xml" type="text/xml"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STATE_DATA>
 <UNIT>
    <STATE>Wisconsin</STATE>
    <GDP>232,300,000,000</GDP>
    <POPULATION>5,800,000</POPULATION>
 </UNIT>
 <UNIT>
    <STATE>Alabama</STATE>
    <GDP>165,800,000,000</GDP>
    <POPULATION>4,900,000</POPULATION>
 </UNIT>
 <UNIT>
    <STATE>California</STATE>   
    <!-- Note: the GDP node for this unit is missing -->
    <POPULATION>39,600,000</POPULATION>
 </UNIT>
 <UNIT>
    <STATE>Texas</STATE>
    <GDP>1,600,000,000,000</GDP>
    <POPULATION>28,300,000</POPULATION>
 </UNIT>
 <UNIT>
    <STATE>Michigan</STATE>
    <GDP>382,000,000</GDP>
    <POPULATION>10,000,000</POPULATION>
 </UNIT>
</STATE_DATA>
        </script>
        <input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
        <button id="myButton" onClick="ehClick()">submit</button>

        <p>input value: <span id="inputValue"></span></p>
        <p>XML tree node position of input value: <span id="nodePosition"></span></p>
        <p>State: <span id="state"></span></p>
        <p>GDP: <span id="gdp"></span></p>
        <p>Population: <span id="population"></span></p>

        <datalist id="myInput">
        <option id="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option id="CA">California</option>
        <option id="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option id="TX">Texas</option>
        <option id="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        </datalist>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets a little bit involved using vanilla [XMLHttpRequest to load XML](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_httprequest.asp). Here is a quick [sample](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_xml).

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "sample.xml" , true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var x, i, xmlDoc, table;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  table = "<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD")
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" + 
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

However, it gets much more complicated esp. if you want to do a cross-domain request.

That's probably the right moment to pick up jQuery to make things easier:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml',
    dataType: 'XML',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function () { },$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml',
    dataType: 'XML',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function () { },
    failure: function () { },
    complete: function (xml) {       
        // Parse the xml file and get data
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); 
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $xml.find('body').each(function () {
           console.log($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```