# Dispay text and not value HTML datalist

Tags: html, angular

I use this code to make a dropdown with an input to search and list items from an array ..

```
  <input list="homebox_id" formControlName="homebox_id"/>
  <datalist id="homebox_id"
    [ngClass]="{invalid: invalidInputs}">
    <option *ngFor="let homebox of homeboxs" value="{{homebox.homebox_id}}">{{homebox.serial_number}}</option>
  </datalist>
```

all is good except this code does not display serial_number but it displays the value i want to send "homebox_id"...What can i do to display the text i want?

Comment: What display are you referring to? The `option` elements?

Comment: yes...i want do display "homebox.serial_number", but it displays the value instead

Comment: I dont get it. You want to display exactly "homebox.serial_number"? Instead of its value? Just use `homebox.serial_number`, not `{{homebox.serial_number}}`

Comment: no no...i want to display the value that come with {{homebox.serial_number}}, but the code displays the value of {{homebox.homebox_id}}.

Comment: Try `[value]="homebox.homebox_id"` instead of `value={{homebox.homebox_id}}`

Comment: tried it already

Comment: Can you try to provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mz3t5h)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882361/show-datalist-labels-but-submit-the-actual-value   this is my exact problem but the solution didnt work for me