# Angular 5 unable to get dropdown values from select

Tags: angular

In my html I have this piece of code

Html...

```
<input type="text" list="select" [(ngModel)]="appSelect" (change)="picked($event.target.value)" />
<datalist id="select">
<option selected="" value="">Select...</option>
<option *ngFor="let i of app; let x = index" [value]="i.info" >{{i.name}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Component...

```
appSelect: any;
      picked(value: any) {
        console.log (value); 
      }
```

above prints what I want but the dropdown shows 2 values. With i.info on the left and i.name on the right in the dropdown column.

```
  Dropdown:  [i.info         i.name]
```

I wanted to show only the i.name in the dropdown column

```
  Dropdown:  [i.name]
```

*Now*...*I have tried a different approach*.

Html....

```
<input type="text" list="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedVal" (ngModelChange)="picked($event)" />
<datalist id="select">
<option selected="" value="">Select...</option>
<option *ngFor="let i of app; let x = index" [ngValue]="i" >{{i.name}}</option>
</datalist>

@Input() selectedVal: string;
      picked(value: any) {
        console.log (value); 
      }
```

Above shows correct value in the dropdown

```
   Dropdown: [i.name]
```

But the issue is that the value passed to picked is `[i.name]` and not `[i.info]`
So how do I get the info passed in while show the name only in the dropdown display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but it works. U can use the javascript find method to search the array and return the correct object like this:

```
  app = [
    { name: 'Dominos', info: 'pizza'},
    { name: 'Taco Bell', info: 'tacos'},
    { name: 'McDonalds', info: 'hamburgers'}
  ]
  selectedValName: string;
  selectedValInfo: string;
  picked(value: any) {
    this.selectedValInfo = this.app.find(obj => obj.name == value).info
    console.log(this.selectedValInfo);
  }
```

see [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9gjrb)

Comment: this worked. thanks you. I was wonder why in the selection it would display twice? why does [value] shows as part of dropdown display?

Comment: @logger - You may find answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29882361/1009922).