# Displaying one value and submitting another through html datalist and *ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datalist, html-datalist

I am creating an autocomplete text box using `<datalist>` with `*ngFor` functionality, however the code I am using is displaying both what I declare as the `[value]` and also what I am inputting between the `<option>` tags...

[Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-datalist-ngfor-display-value)

This is the view of what I get when the autocomplete is present:

[image]

From the code line:

[image]

I would have expected the autocomplete box to only display `{{d.val}}`, but submit `{{d.name}}` when my form is submitted.

Why is it displaying both `{{d.val}}` **AND** `{{d.name}}`, and is there a way in which I can display one and submit another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) tag will by definition render the `value` attribute of each `option` in the select list and then you additionally displayed `{{d.val}}` as a label (aame as setting the `label` attribute). Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29882539/4694994).

`datalist` just behaves differently than `select`. It's not possible to have different display/submit values for it without writing additional javascript code.

Comment: Yup, I agree. :-/ Maybe you can use one of the autocomplete widgets that are out there instead, e.g. https://stackblitz.com/angular/dyrkjjvvxoe?embed=1&file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html

Comment: Or alternatively, you do the mapping by name. The display values should be unique anyway?!