# Hide label from datalist using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I make the React App and I need to show only the `value` and hide the `label` from the datalist. Here is my code below

```
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="Asia" label="Азия"/>
</datalist>
```

Or this

```
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="Asia">Азия</option>
</datalist>
```

[image: Screenshot]
So expected result is hide "Азия"
That's how it looks

Comment: Why do you need to keep the Kirill alphabet versions of the names if you do not need their value or sth?

Comment: @Elvaleryn i can search by value and label both

Comment: Sorry for late response but this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882361/show-datalist-labels-but-submit-the-actual-value