# How to hide label in datalist HTML?

Tags: html

How to hide label in datalist HTML?

```html
<div class="container text-center">
    <div>
        <input class="form-control w-25 mx-auto rounded-pill" list="lst" placeholder="type" id="selectStation">
        <datalist id="lst" class="data">                  
            <option label="W1" value="a">
            <option label="S1" value="b">
            <option label="S2" value="c">        
        </datalist>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdrcg.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need the label in this case?

Comment: Could be similar to select options? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: @MrDeibl it's used in autocomplete. You'd want to hide the label if, for example, you stuff it with synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Just dont set it.

```html
<div class="container text-center">
<div>
    <input class="form-control w-25 mx-auto rounded-pill" list="lst" placeholder="type" id="selectStation">
    <datalist id="lst" class="data">
        <option value="a">
        <option value="b">
        <option value="c">
    </datalist>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean, I want to use the label in the backend but not show it to the user.

Comment: then maybe this answer helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/q/29882361/8823887

Comment: You mean your backend does not know which value has which label? You should not rely on the label - it can be easily changed using the browser's developer tools if someone wants to abuse your system.

Answer (score 0):

Like the HTML Select element, the Datalist has very little flexibility in its design.  Browsers define their own styles for these elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the divider element as hidden.

```html
<div class="container text-center" hidden>
```