# How to pass in item Id to text field tag from datalist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, html-datalist

Currently I learning about Ruby on Rails. So I try to make 1 simple app, but I facing some problem.

I want to pass the item id from select tag datalist to text field tag in rails. But I want to show item name and item code in my select tag datalist. So now I not sure to pass the item id to the text field tag. I have attach my code down below.

expected parameter to backend

["1", "2"]

now it sending parameter to backend

["CM", "NM"]

[Expected View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTzID.png)

So this the code for text field tag and select tag

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= f.label :item, class: 'required'%>
   <% items = Item.where(company_id: current_user.company.id)%>
   <%= text_field_tag "[supplier_item][item_ids][]", nil, {list: 'browser-item'} %>
     <datalist id="browser-item" >
        <%= select_tag "[supplier_item][item_select][]", options_for_select(items.collect{ |item| [item.name, item.item_code]}), {class: "form-control"} %>
      </datalist>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's `items.collect{ |item| [item.name, item.id]}`.

Comment: @razvans but I want to show my item code and item name in dropdownlist. Once user select the item name it need to pass the selected item id to controller. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the expected view you have added in the question is your current view or not as the code would not render that I think.

As you want to display both item name and item_code and pass the item id to backend you can use string concatenation:

```
<%= select_tag "[supplier_item][item_select][]", options_for_select(items.collect{ |item| ["#{item.name} - #{item.item_code}", item.id]}), {class: "form-control"} %>
```

The `option` tag has an attribute `value` which is the value sent to the backend and when creating a `select_tag` using `options_for_select` you pass an array of array values something like this:

```
[['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]
```

This would be rendered as:

```
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
```

i.e., the first value as the label and the second as the actual value of the option tag which would be sent to the backend. This is the reason you are getting the `item_code` on the backend right now instead of `id`.

**Update:** As you are using `datalist` the label doesn't matter it always displays the `value`, there is a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882361/show-datalist-labels-but-submit-the-actual-value) for your case if you wish to have a different display value. An alternative is to use a select tag if that does the job for you or there are some good solutions in the above link.

Comment: Is it possible to show my item name in the text field box and send the id to controller. Cause if now I select it shows the item id in the text field box

Comment: Updated the answer for `datalist`, mostly I explained according to the `select_tag` which is not valid in your case