# Show label instead of option value in input datalist

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I send the `value` value to onChange to the input, but I want the `value` shown in the input to show the `label` value, not the `value`.

```
return (
    <input 
        type="text"
        list="MaterialList"
        name="MaterialId"
        />
    <datalist id="MaterialList">
        <option label="hi" value="0" />
        <option label="hi2" value="1" />
        <option label="hi3" value="2" />
        <option label="hi4" value="3" />
    </datalist>
)
```

The value should be there because we will need the `value` value by adding a button later.
I want to make the `label` show instead of the `value` value being printed on the input tag, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show datalist labels but submit the actual value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882361/show-datalist-labels-but-submit-the-actual-value)

Comment: @ZiaYamin It's similar, but you have to create it using a Hook using react.