# Angular + Typescript: Accept Text Only If Value Inserted is Part of DataList

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, html-datalist

Apologies if this has been answered before, I was unable to find solution specific to my problem hence approaching you all genius minds. So coming right to the problem, this is what I'm facing,

So I have a list that holds approx 2000+ data entries, I am able to display it in a drop down without any problem but I want to provide the user with the option to type to narrowdown the list for the user to easily select from the list. What I've implemented, I've put it in an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhev8y?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

What I'm trying to achieve is that user can insert text to narrowdown the drop down list (as currently working in the Code), but if user insert a value that is not in the list, it gives an error. This error could be anything from Highlighting the Text field RED, or Disabling the SUBMIT button with an error stating invalid input etc etc ...

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you and looking forward to hearing at some wonderful suggestions.

Comment: what your'e looking for is custom validator - https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Comment: `but if user insert a value that is not in the list, it gives an error` Do you mean it SHOULD display an error? Because currently it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Well yes at the moment it just accepts anything that goes into the field, either it's something from dropdown list or any other text, I need to restrict user to stick only to what's in the dropdown list. So if it can pick up an error, then maybe I can disable Submit button and possibly show error stating, please pick value from list etc etc

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882361/show-datalist-labels-but-submit-the-actual-value . if its still not helping then you can get the text when user press submit then validate the text in the array (make sure to lowercase both) if found then pass it if not present message for user